# ADFS Single Sign On can be developed on third party shared hosting server

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, adfs

This question might be silly but needs to know prerequisite before I start reading any documentation of ADFS SSO Integration using asp.net 4.0. So please tell me whether it is possible or not to develop / deploy such kind of system in shared hosting services.

Answer (score 0):

Define shared-hosting services.

If you mean something like Azure, the answer is yes. You can run ADFS in a VM.

ADFS requires Windows server to run.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We are using Shared Hosting Windows Server Services from GoDaddy. Question is will GoDaddy allow me to access ADFS if I am using shared hosting service where I have limited privilege to access server resources